# LinkedIn Share API - create a post with attached PDF

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to use the LinkedIn Share API to publish on behalf of users posts with an attached PDF.

Using the [Create an Image Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#create-an-image-share) section of the docs, I manage to publish a post with an attached PNG image. If, using the same technique, I upload a PDF instead of a PNG image, the post does not get created.

I can't find anywhere in the docs how I would share a PDF. So my question is: is it possible to programmatically create a post with an attached PDF, and if yes, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to docs from the [Marketing developer platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#upload-rich-media), as of October 28th 2019,

> Currently, only jpeg and png formats are supported.

So I guess it is currently not possible to share a post with an attached PDF.